# How to embed many programs to SAS EG project at once

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I work in SAS EG on virtual machine. My EG project contains about 100 SAS programs which are located in different folders (they are not embedded to project). In order to make backup of programs linked to the project I embed them. In order to embed program I right click on it, go to ‘Properties’, and click ‘Embed’ button. I have to repeat these actions 100 times in order to embed all programs.

My question: is there some way to embed many programs to EG project at once?

Comment: I don't know how to automate embedding .sas files in EG. But since your are  storing the .sas files on the OS, why not use the OS to create a backup? Just copy the files to a /backup directory  and copy them there. Or  zip all the *.sas files. Or use version control (git etc).

Comment: Thanks Quentin! It is important for me to store files inside the project for some reason. I found out that there were EG Automation functions which allows programming actions, so I'll try to use them to embed programs automatically.

Comment: If you find a good solution, please add it as an answer.